# Looping sql to match data in bash ksh (AIX) oracle database

Tags: bash, oracle, oracle11g, ksh, database-administration

I want to check via shell if two outputs from a sqlplus command match. Therefore I loop until the variables catching that output are equal and then end the loop, followed by the next set of instructions.

None of the below-mentioned loops are functioning as expected.

I expect the data for `testSeq` and `expectedSeq` to be fetched in realtime and then compared to check the data, if they are equal, exit out and proceed to next step.

```
testSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${primary} << EOF
set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
select max(ARCHIVED_SEQ#) from v\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`

expectedSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${DR}<< EOF
set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
select max(APPLIED_SEQ#) from V\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

while (true)
    do
    while do;

    testSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${primary} << EOF
    set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
    select max(ARCHIVED_SEQ#) from v\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
    EOF`

    expectedSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${DR}<< EOF
    set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
    select max(APPLIED_SEQ#) from V\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
    EOF`

       if [[ "$testSeq" != "$expectedSeq" ]] 
       then
       echo "$DR sync is in Progress." | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com
       else
       sleep 20
    echo "$DR is in sync with ${PRIMARY} and ready to be switched to Snapshot DR" | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com
    done

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    while [[ "$testSeq" != "$expectedSeq" ]]; do
    echo "$DR sync is in Progress." | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com

    sleep 20

    done
    echo "$DR is in sync with ${PRIMARY} and ready to be switched to Snapshot DR" | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

until [ "$expectedSeq" -eq "$testSeq" ]; do
echo "$DR sync is in Progress." | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com
sleep 5 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
break
fi
done
echo "$DR is in sync with ${PRIMARY} and ready to be switched to Snapshot DR" | mailx -s "$DR Refresh update" xxxxx@mail.com
```

Appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work with bash, I didn't test for ksh:

```
expectedSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${DR} <<EOF
set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
select max(APPLIED_SEQ#) from V\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`
testSeq=

while [[ $testSeq != $expectedSeq ]]; do
    if [[ -n testSeq ]]; then
        echo "$DR sync is in Progress."
        sleep 20
    fi
    testSeq=`sqlplus -S user/xxxxxxxxx@${primary} <<EOF
set heading off feedback off pagesize 0 verify off echo off numwidth 15 
select max(ARCHIVED_SEQ#) from V\\$ARCHIVE_DEST_STATUS;
EOF`
    # todo: handle failures
done
echo "$DR is in sync with ${primary} and ready to be switched to Snapshot DR"
```

It's ok to define the expected output outside the loop, provided the table doesn't change during the process. You should be prepared for the case that the query fails, by grepping for errors in the output or so.